# Firebase Android setValue method not working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using firebase and my problem is when I used `setValue`, then I check website, I don't find any changes.

This is my code

```
firebaseRoot = new Firebase("https://xxxx-xxxxx.firebaseio.com/devices");

        Firebase deviceChild = firebaseRoot.child("child");
        deviceChild.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
            {
                Logger.i(LOG, "onDataChange");
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError)
            {
                Logger.i(LOG, "onCancelled");
            }
        });

        deviceChild.setValue("test", new Firebase.CompletionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(FirebaseError firebaseError, Firebase firebase)
            {
                Logger.i(LOG, "onComplete");
            }
        });
```

In log i keep getting

```
 E/FirebaseCrash: Error sending crash report: IOException while sending a crash report
```

It does enter the method `onDataChange`, does this mean it saved it? if yes, then why i can't see it in website?

Since i'm only testing, this is my rules for Database

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

**EDIT**
I've also tried the following code

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference(url);
        myRef.setValue("Hello, World!").addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task)
            {
                Logger.i(LOG, "onComplete");
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e)
            {
                Logger.i(LOG, "onCancelled");
            }
        });
```

Still doesn't work. can anyone tell me what is wrong?

Comment: You're using firebase.com which is deprecated. Use firebase.google.com

Comment: import com.firebase.client.Firebase;  is this what you mean @AbA

Comment: https://firebase.google.com
Start here

Comment: I appreciate it, but I read it, and i can't see the problem, that is why i ask....

Comment: No no. Firebase.com is deprecated. Go to firebase.Google.com

Comment: The Upgrade Guild is helpful: https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-android

Comment: I've edited the question. i've tried that one too. I debugged to make sure it is referenced to my url and it was correct. onComplete & onFailure doesn't fire. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/  that is what I used

Comment: Does your Android manifest declare the INTERNET permission? I don't see anything wrong with the code (using the old SDK is not a big deal here), so it must be an external reason IMHO.

Comment: yes I've Internet permission, and I checked Internet it is working on device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so the problem was that my tablet date, not sure why, was 2015 and I guess some Internet validation somewhere blocked me. The code is working though.